# Can't align the hidden divs to appear at the center of the page vertically and horizontally on visibility

Tags: javascript, css, html, alignment

I  can't align my hidden divs at the center of the page.

If I give position them to relative , the scroll increases as I move to one page to another (i.e that div is not aligned vertically to the center of the page)

Should I place all the three divs in one container div??

Please help!!!

Many thanks in advance..

```
<body>
    <div id ="page1" class="page" style=""visibility:visible>
        content
        <!-- also contains a button that hides this div and makes the
            next div visible -->
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="page">
        content
        <!-- also contains two buttons for back and next div -->
    </div>
    <div id ="page3" class="page">
        content
        <!-- contains two buttons for back and submit -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The css I am using is:

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

The javascript I used is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var currentLayer = 'page1';
function showLayer(lyr){
hideLayer(currentLayer);
document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'visible';
currentLayer = lyr;
}

function hideLayer(lyr){
document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should show the rest of your css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would center your div with the current set up DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/g8r7Z/

```
#page1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ccc;
    width:200px;
    margin:-50px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to make it compatible with IE

Answer (score 0):

center a element using absolute positioning. height and width won't affect the results.

```
.center-align{
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin:auto;
 width: /* works with any width */;
 height: /* works with any height */;
 /* any other style wont effect it */

}
```

*the center alignment holds even when the window resizes*

Answer (score -1):

If you want to center something with absolute position, use the following:

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: -25% 0 0 -25%; /* should be -50% of width/height. */
}
```

Of course you should change `width` and `height` to your desire. As the comment says: The `margin-top` should be `height * -0.5` and `margin-left` should be `width * -0.5`.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vumpq/).

Comment: If you adjust `width` and `height` to a fixed value it will be, yes.

Comment: so isn't there any way where i can align it to center independent of screen size, screen resize??

Comment: What do you mean? The `<div/>` is centered, even if you resize the window. If you want the size of the `<div/>` to be independent of the window size, set it to a fixed `width` like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vumpq/1/

Comment: #page1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ccc;
    width:200px;
    margin:-50px auto 0 auto;
    }                                                                  is there anyway to make it compatible with IE

Comment: My solution is compatible with IE. For other solutions ask the poster.